# Understanding the output of GDB's "bt full" command

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm working on a project with a friend but we have a problem because our application crashes. I ran it in gdb and got this after using the command `bt full`. What does this mean?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff5936700 (LWP 3173)]
0x00007ffff69ece9b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff69ece9b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00000000009a05cc in OutputMessage::append(NetworkMessage const&) ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000000000098fac6 in ProtocolGame::writeToOutputBuffer(NetworkMessage const&) ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00000000009955c0 in ProtocolGame::sendChannelEvent(unsigned short, std::string const&, ChannelEvent_t) ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000000000098cd9f in ProtocolGame::releaseProtocol() ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00000000007e262b in std::_Mem_fn<void (Protocol::*)()>::operator()(Protocol*) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00000000007e1600 in _ZNSt5_BindIFSt7_Mem_fnIM8ProtocolFvvEEPS1_EE6__callIvJEJLm0EEEET_OSt5tupleIJDpT0_EESt12_Index_tupleIJXspT1_EEE ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00000000007dfa94 in _ZNSt5_BindIFSt7_Mem_fnIM8ProtocolFvvEEPS1_EEclIJEvEET0_DpOT_ ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00000000007dc736 in std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Protocol::*)()> (Protocol*)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00000000009fd7a4 in std::function<void ()>::operator()() const ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00000000009fd678 in Task::operator()() ()
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00000000009fd208 in Dispatcher::dispatcherThread() ()
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00000000009fee1b in std::_Mem_fn<void (Dispatcher::*)()>::operator()(Dispatcher*) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00000000009fed6b in _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFSt7_Mem_fnIM10DispatcherFvvEEPS1_EE9_M_invokeIJLm0EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE ()
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00000000009fec69 in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Dispatcher::*)()> (Dispatcher*)>::operator()() ()
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00000000009fec02 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Dispatcher::*)()> (Dispatcher*)> >::_M_run() ()
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00007ffff71a3400 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007ffff66b4b50 in start_thread ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007ffff69a60ed in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

I compiled my program normally as I always do.

Comment: It means you crashed in `OutputMessage::append` when calling a C library function. It also means that you didn't compile with `-g`.

Comment: compile with full debugging symbols (`-ggdb3`) on, run in `gdb`. try going `up` one level in the debugger after the crash to verify that your `OutputMessage` and `NetworkMessage` are both non-null. See what was being called in `libc` that died for more indication of what bad data you might be passing it.

Comment: It means it is highly likely `OutputMessage::append` is invoking **undefined behavior**, probably by hitting an invalid pointer (NULL or no longer determinate) and sending it to a function in libc.

Comment: @PaulR Should I use the -g flag with make?